# Uipath: Connecting a robot to the Orchestrator Issue

Tags: rpa, uipath

I am using Uipath Enterprise Trial latest edition on a remote Windows Server 2008R2 Standard. 
I am trying to connect a robot to orchestrator community edition and I am getting the following error when I click on connect to connect the robot:

"An error occurred while sending the request"

- I added the machine correctly and I created a robot attached to it.
- I double checked my credentials and there is no error
- I verified the machine key and it is also correct
- I checked the Uipath service robot and it is running.
- I restarted the robot and the error persists

**To be noted:** 
- I did not use orchestrator Enterprise edition because the installation requirements need approval from the security and IT team (Pending)
- I tested using Uipath Enterprise Studio with orchestrator community edition on my personal computer and it works fine. 
- My orchestrator and my robot version are both 2018 hence compatible

Did anyone have a similar issue and can assist me on this?

Please let me know if there is anything else I need to clarify.

Comment: Does your machine have the [required updates](https://studio.uipath.com/docs/software-requirements) needs for a 2008R2 server?

Comment: I will check it out and let you know. Thank you for you comment MUIferts

Comment: Hello @MUlferts . Yes I have all the updates. I actually had no problem installing studio. The issue arises only when I try to connect a robot.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked with the system admins. Firewall is blocking cloud redirection on my machine and that is the reason behind the error